# Can't save UIPickerView value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

Have `UIPickerView` with two rows. Trying to save value of each row in `NSUserDefaults`. Didn't used before `NSUserDefaults`. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    NSUserDefaults *defaultsPicker = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    picker = [defaultsPicker objectForKey:@"picker"] ;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *ar1 = [NSArray array];
    for (int i = 150; i <= 210; i++)
        ar1 = [ar1 arrayByAddingObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    [ar1 retain];
    self.array1 = ar1;

    NSArray *ar2 = [NSArray array];
    for (int j = 40; j <= 130; j++)
        ar2 = [ar2 arrayByAddingObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
    [ar2 retain];
    self.array2 = ar2;


    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

And NSUserDefaults is in IBAction

```
-(IBAction)calculate {
    NSUserDefaults *defaultsPicker = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultsPicker setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0 ]] forKey:@"picker"];
    [defaultsPicker synchronize];

    //bla bla
}
```

When I press the button, app crashes and log is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber selectedRowInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x690df40'
```

**UPDATE**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == secondArrayComponent) {
        return [self.array2 count];
    }else {
        return [self.array1 count];
    }
}


#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == secondArrayComponent) {
        return [self.array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }else {
        return [self.array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`
 delegate method add the following code and it should save to NSUserDefaults

**UPDATE**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == secondArrayComponent) {
        return [self.array2 count];
    }else {
        return [self.array1 count];
    }
}


#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == secondArrayComponent) {
        return [self.array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }else {
        return [self.array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {    
    NSInteger selectedRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"picker"];
}
```

That should do as long as you make sure you have set your UIPickerView's delegate as "self" in interface builder or in your code. Also in your .h file make sure you have `<UIPickerViewDelegate>`

**UPDATE 2**
To check whether your NSUserDefaults have saved use this piece of code in an -(IBAction) of your choosing

```
NSInteger pickerRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"picker"];
NSLog(@"%i", pickerRow);
```

Comment: okay edited. You should be able to just copy and paste that and it should work

Comment: Doesn't work. Do I need my old code in viewDidLoad and in -(IBAction) calculate ?

Comment: you still need the code in your viewDidLoad yes, but not the -(IBAction) calculate. Instead it will be saved in your NSUserDefaults everytime you spin your UIPickerView to a value.

How are you checking if your NSUserDefaults are getting saved? I edited the above code for a way to check if the value has been saved.

Comment: How can I add a second row to NSUserDefaults? Now works just a first row.